# Can I move Postgres indexes between servers?

Tags: postgresql, database-administration

I want to have the ability to generate a table and its indexes on one server, then do a `COPY ... WITH BINARY` to produce the bin file for both table and indexes and move the data to our second server for import. `COPY` works great for tables, but not for indexes. How can I move the indexes as well?

Answer (score 0):

Use the `pg_get_indexdef` function to get the index definitions and execute them on the other server.

Comment: Care to explain?

Comment: I want to create the index on a separate server as it takes 30 minutes and then move it to the main server if possible which would take about a minute.

Comment: That is impossible.

Answer (score 0):

Indexes cannot be dumped and moved between servers. Only option is to da a binary backup with for example `pg_basebackup` and use that as a start.

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-pgbasebackup.html

Note: this will copy the whole server. After that you can delete the unneeded objects on the new server.